# Double integral $\iint_{D} z \ \mathbf{e}_z\cdot\mathbf{n}\ \mathrm{d}S=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ over the surface of a hemisphere

Tags: calculus, integration

I am to use the method of projection to show that $\iint_{D} z \ \mathbf{e}_z\cdot\mathbf{n}\ \mathrm{d}S=\frac{2\pi}{3}$, where $D$ is the surface of the unit hemisphere centered at the origin and $\textbf{n}$ is the outward pointing unit normal to the surface. I was a little confused by the hint given in the question, which gave the value of the integral $\int r\sqrt{1-r^2} \ \mathrm{d}r$ as a third. Why exactly is this relevant to the problem? Using spherical polar coordinates, surely there shouldn't be a need for a $\mathrm{d}r$ term, as we are integrating over the surface of a hemisphere with constant radius?

Comment: If you use cylindrical coordinates, though, you will get that term.

Comment: I suppose so, but isn't it usually customary to use spherical polar coordinates?

Comment: I don't know about "customary."  People use the coordinate system they feel more comfortable with and that makes the calculation simple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that helps, but to get the value of the integral use the divergence theorem. The answer follows directly knowing the volume of half a ball of radius 1.